# Prove that matrix $A = \sum_k^{n}x_k\lambda_ky_k^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Prove that matrix $\ A = \sum_{k=1}^n {\bf x}_k \lambda_k {\bf y}_k^T.\ $ If $\ {\bf x}_k\ $ and $\ {\bf y}_k\ $ are the corresponding eigenvector from the left and from the right of $\lambda_k$. Any idea how to start on this proof? Also $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Comment: Prove that matrix $A$ is *what*?

Comment: is equal to that summation

Comment: Please use bold face for vectors

Comment: What do you mean bold face?

Comment: I expect that there must be some other conditions, since this is false for $A=\small{\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}}$.